# sql - fetch all user friends

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wish to query 3 different tables. 
[image]

My approach would be getting the the friends from **FRIENDS TABLE**. So, the output would be: 
[image]

I tried having this solution

```
SELECT users.firstname, users.lastname, 
users.screenname, profile.profile_pic, friends.friend_id
FROM website.users users
INNER JOIN website.friends friends ON (users.user_id = friends.friend_id)
LEFT  JOIN profile ON (friends.friend_id = profile.user_id)
WHERE (friends.user_id = "12052822" or friends.friend_id = "12052822")
```

Problem is when it matches one record, it outputs the the column **"friend.user_id"**. That's not what I want to do! If the user is logged in, **a query will fetch all his friends**... How can I do that in an easier and better way?

Comment: Just a note: you don't need `users.user_id`, the ID for your users would be `users.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` and `user_id` columns in the `users` table are at least confusing?  Why two 'identifier' columns?  Which of the two joins with `friend.user_id`?  Is it the same column that joins with `friend.friend_id`?  And is the objective to display all the names where the `friends.user_id` is the user who just logged in, or all the names where the `friends.friend_id` is the user who just logged in, or both?

Until further clarification is forthcoming, I will assume the result set should include both lists of friends: the people who have been friended by the user and the people who have friended the user.  I will also assume that the `users.user_id` column is the joining column.

We can write this easily as a UNION, noting that a UNION will eliminate duplicate entries for the case where the user who logged in has friended a user who has also friended the user who logged in (so there are two entries in the `friends` table with the same pair of values in `user_id` and `friend_id`.

Going in for TDQD (Test Driven Query Design), we can write (assuming the newly logged in user is `user_id = 12052822`):

#### Users friended by user 12052822

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.screenname, p.profile_pic
  FROM website.friends AS f
  JOIN website.users   AS u ON f.friend_id = u.user_id
  JOIN website.profile AS p ON p.user_id   = u.user_id
 WHERE f.user_id = 12052822;
```

#### Users who have friended user 12052822

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.screenname, p.profile_pic
  FROM website.friends AS f
  JOIN website.users   AS u ON f.user_id = u.user_id
  JOIN website.profile AS p ON p.user_id = u.user_id
 WHERE f.friend_id = 12052822;
```

#### Both sets of users

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.screenname, p.profile_pic
  FROM website.friends AS f
  JOIN website.users   AS u ON f.friend_id = u.user_id
  JOIN website.profile AS p ON p.user_id   = u.user_id
 WHERE f.user_id = 12052822;
UNION
SELECT u.user_id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.screenname, p.profile_pic
  FROM website.friends AS f
  JOIN website.users   AS u ON f.user_id = u.user_id
  JOIN website.profile AS p ON p.user_id = u.user_id
 WHERE f.friend_id = 12052822;
```

You can test and debug each of the component queries separately, and then combine them to create the final answer.